# using two versions (with code conflicts) of a 3rd party jar in one maven project

Tags: java

Our maven project includes one 3rd third jar, which has two different versions.

- A-1.0.jar (with function `A()` removed in version 2)
- A-2.0.jar (with function `B()` added (not in version 1))

How to organize my codes to support 1.0's api and 2.0's api at the same time ?

Comment: This looks dangerous, try to have your code only use the latest version.

Comment: The best way is to migrate code in function A() or function B() to the same version of dependencies as it will take you into less future headaches with code maintenance. If the APIs versions are fully compatible you can exclude one of them. You may consider code refactoring in this case

Comment: Did you look at the maven shade plugin ? it has an option to relocate code from a dependency to another package. This can enable you to import /use both version at the same time.

Comment: We can't discard version 1.0. our code should support two version at the same time. but for the same functions, these two different version jars have different function name.

Comment: Do you need to use the 2 versions at the same time for your artifact to work, or do you wish to leave the option of choosing the version of the 3rd party jar to the users of your artifact (but ultimately, there will be only one of the versions on the classpath at runtime) ?

Comment: I also would suggest the Maven Shade Plugin, but really, your approach sounds a little weird.

Comment: @Thierry I want to leave the option to choose which version to be built because of our two customers having different environment(A1.0 and A2.0), so I wish maintain only one code suite to build different target version to support different customer's environments.

Answer (score 2):

A possible way of doing this is to have no dependency on library A (not version 1.0, nor version 2.0) in your project.

You need to create three other build (maven for example) projects / artifacts, which will be wrappers for the different library versions.

You'll have :

- AbstractWrapper project artifact
- Wrapper of version 1 artifact
- Wrapper of version 2 artifact

In the AbstractWrapper, you'll have an interface / abstract class, that reproduce the api from the library `A` you want to use. This is the only [of the 3] artifacts that will be declared in the dependencies of your main project. This abstract wrapper do not depend on your project, nor on lib `A`.

Then each wrapper will depend on AbstractWrapper (to get the interface definition), and on the `A` library, either version 1 or version 2.

The tricky point now is to get the wrapper implementation (that will be available at runtime) to register in your main project. It depends a lot on the packaging and the runtime environnements (standalone jar, osgi bundle, servlet spec 2.5-, servlet spec 3.0+, springframework...), i let you do some research on plugin registration for your specific environnement.

The ugliest thing you could come up with is a `Class.forName()` trying both implementation you did, and using the first it finds (casting the class you get to the abstract wrapper interface).

Finally for the clients using the version 1.0 of the lib `A`, you tell them to depends on your main project and your wrapper of lib version 1, and the others on your main project and lib version 2.

Comment: Thanks. Wrapper of version 1 artifact will depends on A1.0.jar, Wrapper 2 will depends on A2.0.jar, when my project includes both of them, I think there is still conflicts happens??

Comment: Your project will include none : it will only include the project that contains the abstraction (interface / abstract class, maybe some DTO). Then, the clients that wants to use lib version 1 will have to depends on your project, and the wrapper of lib v1, and the others that want to use the lib in version 2 will have to depends on your project and the wrapper of lib v2.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. But you can exclude one or the other version with the  tag like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectD</groupId> <!-- Exclude Project-D from Project-B -->
      <artifactId>Project-D</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

See the documentation here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html